# Select from three tables and show the results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to follow tutorials for select and joining multiple tables but can't understand it yet. So I have tables: `images`, `favorites`, `users`.

`images` - `image_id`, `image_name` ... etc

`users` - `id`, `name` ... etc

`favorites` - `image_id`, `id`

In table `favorites`, `image_id` represent id of the image and `id` is id of the user. On the image there is button `Add to favorite`. Now I want to display all the images which user added to his collection of favorites.

This is what I tried but doesn't work

```
SELECT f.image_id, f.id
FROM favorites
JOIN users u ON f.id = u.id
JOIN images i ON f.image_id = i.image_id
WHERE u.id = 2
```

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'f.image_id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed alias `f` in the query

```
SELECT f.image_id, f.id
FROM favorites f
JOIN users u ON f.id = u.id
JOIN images i ON f.image_id = i.image_id
WHERE u.id = 2
```

Comment: Oh, thank's. Didn't saw this single `f`. It's work now.